# Minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q $ of a given root.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2} $ over $\Bbb Q $

setting $ x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2} $ we have $x^2 -2= \sqrt2 $ and $(x^2-2)^2-2=0$

i believe this is the desired polynomial but i am not sur ehow to show that it is minimal.

I tried writing $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2} =\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} }{2a}$ thinking that it might be a good place to start but in the end  didn't get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(x^2-2)^2-2=x^4-4x^2+2$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.

**Edit:** Irreducible and minimal being equivalent.

If $f$ is a polynomial such that $f(a)=0$ for some $a$, then if it is not irreducible, i.e. $f=gh$, then either $g(a)=0$ or $h(a)=0$, so $f$ isn't minimal.

On the other hand, if $f$ is not the minimal polynomial for $a$, then there is some minimal polynomial $g$, and we have $f=gh+g_0$ for some $h,g_0$ with the degree of $g_0$ less than the degree of $g$. $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=0$ means $g_0(a)=0$. Since $g$ is minimal and $g_0$ has lower degree, we must have $g_0=0$ so $f=gh$ is not irreducible.

Comment: I wasn't sure "minimal" meant irreducible ???

Comment: @Faust It is one of equivalent definitions. The minimal polynomial is the unique irreducible monic with the given number as a root.

Comment: @Faust I added a few brief lines about why those two are the same.